# CSS3 auto-fill problem?

Tags: css

for example:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

I need `#left`'s width is fixed while `#right` auto fills the space left in `#container`?
How to achieve this with **CSS3** ? I am using IE9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use any of the new features from CSS3.

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
#container {
  border: 3px solid red;  
}

#left {
  width: 100px;  
  float: left;   
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

#right {
  background: yellow;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jDEy5/).

Answer (score 1):

Alex's example is good so I'll use his code, but I think maybe you're looking for `overflow:hidden` on the right side it will not wrap below the left.

see new **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDEy5/2/)**

```
#container {
  border: 3px solid red;  
}

#left {
  width: 100px;  
  float: left;   
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

#right {
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thought about it, but a 50/50 call it's a different solution, I came with my solution, saw there was an answer with similar code, (but IMHO not the same as mine) I didn't downvote, I added an alternative - OP is free to accept which ever answer is best suited or whichever they feel led to a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the floats, try using `display: table-cell;` (won't work in IE<8):

```
#container {
  border: 3px solid red;  
}
#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
#left {
  min-width: 100px;  
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
#right {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDEy5/4/)